# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am having trouble on posting the lists of data in my table, I hope you guys can help me with this issue, this is the error i am getting **Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

```
  const columns = [
    {
     name: "name",
     label: "Name",
     options: {
      filter: true,
      sort: true,
     }
    },
    {
     name: "dateregistered",
     label: "Date Registered",
     options: {
      filter: true,
      sort: false,
     }
    },
    {
     name: "department",
     label: "Department",
     options: {
      filter: true,
      sort: false,
     }
    },

   ];
   
   const data = [

      posts.map(post => [{name: 'post.firstname', dateregistered: 'post.date', department: 'post.department'}])
    
       ];

  return (
    <>
        <MUIDataTable
          title={"Deactivated Users"}
          data={data}
          columns={columns}
          options={options}
        />
    </>
  )
```

Comment: Maybe try `const data = posts.map(post => ...)`? I think the issue is that you are nesting an array inside of another array.

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: I remove the `const data =` **[]**

Comment: And what about `const data = posts.map(post => ({name: 'post.firstname', dateregistered: 'post.date', department: 'post.department'}))` also you are nesting an array inside an array here when wrapping the object inside an array.

Comment: @juanireyes man your a genius thanks !! can you post your answer?

Comment: let me post it with a clear explanation so other people can reach it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two problems in your `data` constant. The first one, the `.map` method returns an array, so there is no need to wrap that value inside an array keys `[]`. The other problem is that you are wrapping the `.map` return state object in array keys too, that is why the error of creating an object is displayed, because you are returning arrays inside the main mapped array `[[{ name: ... }], [{ name: ... }]]`.

So basically the solution for your issue would be:

```
const data = posts.map(post => ({name: 'post.firstname', dateregistered: 'post.date', department: 'post.department'}))
```

Where the parenthesis allows the map method to directly return the object.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that data is being created as an array in an array in an array. This is why when you try `const data = posts.map(post => ...)` the error persists, as there is still an array in an array. After you try the above, also re-write

```js
post => [{name: 'post.firstname', dateregistered: 'post.date', department: 'post.department'}]
```

to

```js
post => ({name: 'post.firstname', dateregistered: 'post.date', department: 'post.department'})
```

(Changing the square brackets to round)

P.S When you map over posts to build the data, you build a object with the the key "name" and the value "'post.firstname'". That value is a string literal and not accessing some other JS object (It will make "post.firstname" the value for all the post's. Same goes for the other keys.

Comment: Sorry, looks like I was just a minute too late!

Comment: Didn't realized the nested string values though, nice job there.